# Php class inheritance and rewrite?

Tags: php, class

```
<?php
class A {
    private function foo(){
        echo 1;
    }
    public function test(){
        $this->foo();
    }
}
class B extends A{
    public function  foo(){
        echo 0;
    }
}
$b = new B();
echo $b->test();
```

Class B inherits from class A. Why does the output result in 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Because `A#foo()` is **private**, therefore `A` only knows about `A#foo()` in `A#test()`. If you made `A#foo()` protected or public, you would see `0` instead

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#87413

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because private methods can't be overridden. So, when `A.foo` is defined again in class B its scope is different and `A.test` can only see `A.foo`